# Better syntax for re-raising an exception only if an exception occurred?

Tags: python, exception

I find myself doing this when I want to catch an exception, always run some specific code, then re-raise the original exception:

```
try:
    error = False
    # do something that *might* raise an exception
except Exception:
    error = True
finally:
    # something I *always* want to run
    if error:
        raise
```

I am using the flag because calling `raise` without a previous exception raises a `TypeError`. Is there a more Pythonic way to do with without the flag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Raise the exception in the except handler:

```
try:
    # do something that *might* raise an exception
except Exception:
    raise
finally:
    # something I *always* want to run
```

The `finally` suite is *always* going to be executed wether or not you re-raised the exception.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The `try` clause is executed, including any `except` and `else` clauses. If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The `finally` clause is executed. If there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the `finally` clause.

Note that if the `finally` suite uses a `break` or `return` statement, the saved exception *is* discarded:

> If the `finally` clause executes a return or break statement, the saved exception is discarded:
>
> ```
> def f():
>     try:
>         1/0
>     finally:
>         return 42
>
> >>> f()
> 42
> ```

but if you issue a `break`, `continue` or `return` in the `try` suite, the `finally` suite is executed still:

> When a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement is executed in the `try` suite of a `try`...`finally` statement, the `finally` clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’

Note that before Python 2.5, you could not even combine `except` and `finally` suites in the same `try` statement; see [PEP 341: Unified try/except/finally](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-341-unified-try-except-finally). Instead, you were expected to nest `try` statements:

```
try:
    try:
        # some code that could raise an exception
    except SomeException:
        # exception handler
finally:
    # cleanup code, always executed
```

Comment: +1 and don't forget the opportunity to add useful debug info to the exception before it goes out...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, so the `finally` block essentially acts like another **outer** `try...except` block?

Comment: @JaceBrowning: Yes. In the past, you could not use a `finally` if there was an `except` block and you *had* to nest them. See http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-341-unified-try-except-finally

Answer (score 3):

`finally` will *always* execute, no matter what happens in the `try` or `except` block, or whether the `except` block is even present.

Both of these will work:

```
try:
    # do something that *might* raise an exception
finally:
    # something I *always* want to run
```

```
try:
    # do something that *might* raise an exception
except Exception:
    raise
finally:
    # something I *always* want to run
```